# Google App Script: range.setDataValidations(rules) takes very long time (sometime fails)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Following code to avoid data validation error while setting value to range.

```
const dataValidationRules = range.getDataValidations();
range.setDataValidation(null);
/*some business logic*/
range.setDataValidations(dataValidationRules ); //takes long time or even sometime fails
```

**range** has around 9k rows and 10-15 columns. It works fine when **range** has few rows.

Please let me know why **setDataValidations** is not working with large ranges.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `/*some business logic*/`.  Are you sure it is the `setDataValidation()` causing the slow down?

Comment: @TheWizEd, yeah I logged the time and it was specifically this line. Business logic is to paste data into range (it successfully gets finished)

Comment: Google Sheets caches writes, so it remains unclear whether the slowdown is because of data validation rules. Try again without the business logic. The bad performance may also be because of spreadsheet structure which may slow down writes. See [these optimization tips](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/102271339?msgid=102278707).

Comment: You logged the time just before and just after that command?  Because I ran a test case of 2000 rows 3 column and it only took 0.42 sec.

Comment: Just now 9000 rows 10 columns 1.5 sec.  I get rules within data range, set to null then set to the old rules.

Comment: I discovered that if you don't fill in a value in a cell with a data validation rule it does not count toward data range.  I had columns 2 to 10 empty so my data range was only 1 column.  When i selected a value from list for every cell the time went to 22 sec.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. Could you provide the error in the logs? that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way

Comment: If each column has its own validation rule, and each of those rules applies to the whole column, you can possibly set those rules faster by using the likes of `const ruleA = sheet.getRange('A2').getDataValidation()`, and `sheet.getRange('A2:A'). setDataValidation(ruleA)` instead of using `range.setDataValidations()`. Worth a try?

Comment: In your situation, when Sheets API is used instead of Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp), will the same result occur?